# First mouse call of JQuery's .show() does not display animation

Tags: jquery

Hi everyone (first post!). I'm a JQuery and Javascript newbie.

I'm working on the following website: http://www.beautifulinteractions.com/lombo/

I made a custom .js file with my own functions calling JQuery selectors and methods. I call the startup() function from  tag and two divs (the menu and and footer) come in in the proper way.

However, the first time (and only the first) I click on a menu element (triggering a .show() call via onclick="javascript:showContent(URL)") the target div gets visibile but does not fade in - it just appears. Every other time I click on a menu item the animation works fine.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help.

```
millis = 600;

function startup() {
    $('#hiddenMenu').show(millis, foo());
    $('#footer').show(millis, foo());
    //$(""+"#hiddenContent"+"").show('slow', foo());
}

function showContent(URL) {
    $('#hiddenContent').hide(millis, function() {
                                        $('#hiddenContent').load(URL);
                                        $('#hiddenContent').show(millis, foo());
     });

}
function hideContent() {
    $('#hiddenContent').hide(millis, foo());
}

function foo() {
    //Do-Nothing
}`
```

Comment: just as a sidenote, you need references to pass a function as parameter. You can do that just by using the function name, without the paranthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your `showContent` function with the following:

```
function showContent(URL) {
    $('#hiddenContent').hide(millis, function() {
        $(this).load(URL, function() {
            $(this).show(millis, foo());
        });
    });
}
```

It could be due to the fact the the `$.load` call does not complete before the `show` line is executed. Moving the `.show` into `$.load`'s callback might do the trick.

Comment: @Jacopo - Try @jAndy's suggestion: `$(this).show(millis, foo);`

Comment: adding the .show() into .load() callback did the trick. Thank you very much. I appreaciate all this.

Answer (score 0):

You already tried to get a output off the `startup()` function? by console or alert? so you know if you script is running or not.

and a little tip.. when you using `onclick` you dont have to use `javascript:`

so you should do something like this:

```
onclick="startup();"
```

should be enough!

EDIT:

make you var millis to this:

```
var millis = 600;
```

without var your script will not work in IE

Comment: Thank you for your precious hints. startup() works perfectly as does showContent(URL) from the second call.